# Cropp Image to fit ImageView based on X axis

Tags: android, image, imageview, android-imageview

[image]

As you can see in image, we have two type of `ImageView`, one type `Horizontal` and another `Vertical`. We want to load image to them in the way that bitmap fill the ImageView, images can be smaller ( like image `#1` ) or bigger and taller ( like image `#2` ).

Our goal is something like shown in image, we want to scale images on their `X-Axis` and crop overfllow of drawable in `Y-Axis`

We tried almost all `scale-type`, but results does not satisfy us, unfortunately

Comment: you want to scale image width to view width and crop vertical end of image , right?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make width of `drawable` match  with `ImageView`'s width you can use `Matrix`:

```
public Matrix scaleWidthMatrix(int imageWidth, int viewWidth) {
  Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
  float scale = (float) viewWidth / imageWidth;
  scaleMatrix.setScale(scale, scale);
  return scaleMatrix;
}
```

This method returns a scale `Matrix` to scale image so that its width matches with `ImageView` and it does not consider height factor, Therefore parts of scaled `drawable` that is out of `ImageView`'s boundary (in this case lower part of `drawable`) will be cropped.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);

    iv.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(
       new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            int imageWidth = iv.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
            Matrix matrix = scaleWidthMatrix(imageWidth, iv.getWidth());
            //we should setScaleType to Matrix in order to use image matrix
            iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
            iv.setImageMatrix(matrix);
            //No need to call again so remove it
            iv.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

**PS:**
`OnPreDrawListener` gets called just before `onDraw` method gets invoked. At this point, all views in the tree have been measured so you can pass valid arguments to `scaleWidthMatrix` method.